# Website takes very long to load, order, and display statistics

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a database where a few statistics are stored (PlayerID, Time, Kills, Deaths), 7 in total but these are enough to explain.

What I did was load the table in php, create an array with all the statistics (including statistics that are a product of multiple statistics, kills per death for example), sort them, and cut the top 10.

Then I passed this top10-array as JSON to javascript, where I just created tr- and td-elements and made the respective tables append them.

However, with just 10 different sets of statistics, it took an eternity (like 30 seconds I'd say) to load the page. My guess was that the sorting takes too long for the server, so I tried just passing the initial array to javascript and put the sorting part in /* */, to test if it would go any faster. It did not.

Afterwards I turned the sorting back on, but disabled the javascript part and just displayed it with var_dump(). It still didn't go much faster.

The actual code is kinda long and I think this isn't a question that you need the code for, but I can still post the code if you really need it. What exactly is causing the load time, and what would be the best way to sort and display the statistics?

Edit: I forgot to say that using ORDER BY in the SQL query doesn't work, because I need the to calculate some statistics using others.

Comment: You should probaby use `EXPLAIN` to see the potential problem with your SQL query. By the way, if you don't put your query and your table structure, we won't be able to give you much optimisation tips, except adding indexes if they're missing.

Comment: What is the criteria to choose top 10?

Comment: The query is just "SELECT * FROM Statistics". The table columns are just 8 integer values.

Comment: I'm sorting the array in descending/ascending order, and then just use array_slice($arr, 0, 10)

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you spend all you time on retrieving and processing the whole data set, and then you throw away everything but top 10 records.

Without seeing the model and understanding how the top 10 are selected, the only advice would be to rethink you model, decide on an indexed field by which you would be able to fetch just the top 10 records, and do the calculations for that field before you save statistics into DB.

It also depends on which operation is more time-sensitive for you - SELECT or UPDATE (i.e when you fetch or save statistics). But I bet couple of math operations before you save data will not affect much the time spent on saving the data. But will greatly improve time spent on generating some reports, including top 10 report.

Comment: So it would be faster to just save Kills, Deaths, and KillsPerDeaths in the database and then get them with some select-top-orderby query? I thought I was being smart for leaving as much unnecessary data as possible..

Comment: Well, say you have 10000 records. You waste time on calculating statistics for 9990 just to figure out the other 10.

Comment: Alright so this was only part of the solution, the main problem was that I was loading the player information (name, accountid, 4 columns total) for every single top 10 entry. Now I pass the player information as a second array, that gets filled with playerID as needed, with array_key_exists.

Your answer also helped reducing loading time though, and it is very good that you told me this before there were hundreds of records, which is where this makes a difference.

Comment: Glad your were able to address the issue! Good luck!